# Flatten an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to flatten an array with javascript but without recurssion and without prebuilt function.

This is the code but it dose not flatten the whole array and i want to know what is wrong with my code

input : `[1, [2], [3,8, [[4]],9],[5,6]]`
output : `[1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6]`

Code :

```js
flat = function(array) {
  const output = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array[i] == 'number') {
      output.push(array[i])
    } else {
      let arr = array[i]

      let n = 0
      while (n < arr.length) {
        if (typeof arr[n] == 'number') {
          output.push(arr[n])
          n++
        } else {
          arr = arr[n]
          n--
          console.log(arr, n);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return output
}
```

Comment: The snippet editor has 4 distinct sections. All of them have a "name"/purpose. Putting JavaScript in the HTML section of the editor doesn't make much sense. -> [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: _"but without recurssion"_ - You won't find a solution without recursion that works with any sort of nested arrays because anything else is just not reasonably feasible.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time for me in stackoverflow

Comment: Is the "without recursion" limitation self-imposed or part of an assignment? I ask because an array with unlimited depth of child arrays is a clearly recursive structure and recursive tools are the best match for those.

Comment: I mean without using a recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do, but it involves managing a stack yourself, manually:

```js
const input = [1, [2], [3, 8, [[4]], 9], [5, 6]];

const result = [];
const stack = [{current: input, pos: 0}];
while (stack.length > 0) {
  let {current, pos} = stack.pop();
  if (pos < current.length) {
    let item = current[pos++];
    stack.push({current, pos});
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      stack.push({current: item, pos: 0});
    } else {
      result.push(item);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

This is what a recursive approach would do in the background, more or less. If your concern about recursion was that you don't like/understand it, not sure that you will find this one more likeable.